# Woocommerce product listing by store location

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, woocommerce

The resources described below:

1. Wordpress website with woocommerce plugin activated.
2. Sample products are entered in the woocommerce store.
3. These Products are having categories such as (T-shirts, pants, hats and store name).
4. WP multi store locator plugin to get user location and showcase nearby stores based on location.

The problem is described below:
1. user should get option to select the nearby store and products gets sorted based on this store name.

P.S: The wp multi store locator plugin is not necessary, if there is any other alternative plugin which can solve this, it is good. tried numerous wordpress plugin to solve this but no plugin is connecting store locator to product category.

Note: This type of functionality is available on major store sites such as Walmart, Best Buy, Loblaws etc. They ask user their location and set it as main category to display the products available at that location in same city.

Answer (score 0):

Which plugin you have tried? I think WooCommerce Geolocation Based Products may meet your requirement.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-geolocation-based-products/

Comment: This plugin is working for country, state or city. It does not works for different stores in one city.